# Multiple images top and bottom in one element css3?

Tags: wordpress, css

In Wordpress I have this kind of structure in my primary menu:

```
#menu-primary .sub-menu {    
    background:url('images/submenu_background_top.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width:159px;
    padding-bottom:6px;    
}
```

The image `submenu_background_top.png` is at the top of `.submenu`-element which is a an ul.

I want to align another background at the top of the `.submenu` - element (*which is 6px high (therefore the `padding-bottom:6px`)*)

In "normal cases" I could put in an absoletely positioned element at the bottom of the .submenu element and put an image in there, but I don't want to change the html (for primary menu) of the theme I'm using.

I looked at css3 multiple images, but I understand I could use right, main, left -image separated by a comma, ***but I would rather like*** topimage, bottomimage separated by a comma - I couldn't see the ability to achieve that in css3. I have no problems using css3 because it's easy to create an image-fallback.

```
#menu-primary .sub-menu {    
    background:url('images/submenu_background_top.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width:159px;
    /* How to put a bottom image here that is 6px high? (but still have image above in this element) */
    padding-bottom:6px;    
}
```

Comment: Could you not combine the two images into 1?

Comment: The top-image is a gradient with border top, left and right (with gradient on the borders), and the lower image has gradient and a rounded border with drop-shadow, so I don't think so?

Comment: You could use an `:after` pseudo element if you don't want to use CSS3 http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/5xR3A/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to comma-separate your background values for the different images, like this:

```
background-image: url('images/submenu_background_top.png'), url('images/submenu_background_bottom.png');
background-position: top left, bottom left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5c8n/

Comment: Thanks a lot! But position in this order was what I was looking for: background-position: bottom left, top left; :-)